# error: 'x' argument pf 'dtime' intrinsic at <1> must be of kind 4

Tags: fortran, gfortran

My understanding of programming is very limited so I hope I am making sense.

I made a change to a fixed variable in a program (the program is called NAFnoise; I was using the .exe but it came with the source code and I made the change there). The program is written in Fortran and is in multiple files. I am using gfortran to compile it and most of the files works without a problem. One file, however, is giving me trouble. And I didn't even make changes to it. It is giving error messages that is like this:

> error: 'x' argument pf 'dtime' intrinsic at <1> must be of kind 4

The same message appears for `etime`. The only times those (I am guessing they are) functions and variables inside them are referenced as shown below:

```
IMPLICIT                        NONE                                  

   ! Local variables.                                                 

INTEGER(4)                   :: klo,khi,i,n_in,nvar,nj,j1,j2,ivar,nok,nbad
REAL(DbKi)                   :: kk2, Isumwell, Isum, Itot,eps,h1,hmin
REAL(DbKi)                   :: ys1,ys2,poverall,phipot
REAL(DbKi)                   :: bigben(2),bigben2(2),dtime,etime
REAL(DbKi)                   :: phif(10)

COMPLEX(DbKi)                :: value,dval1,dval2,dval11,dval12,dval22 
COMPLEX(DbKi)                :: btrans,btrans1,btrans2,btrans11,btrans12,btrans22
COMPLEX(DbKi)                :: bbb,bbb1,bbb2
```

and

```
  write(*,*) etime(bigben2),dtime(bigben)
```

and

```
 write(*,*) etime(bigben2),dtime(bigben)
```

I am guessing the program was found when the author included it in the source folder, so I am not sure what went wrong. The variable I change should have nothing to do with this. Does it have something to do with the compiler? How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DTIME is a non-standard GNU function described in the manual https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/DTIME.html. It requires an argument to be of kind 4. That is the single precision under the default settingd for gfortran.

Probably, `DbKi` means double precision instead for you. Change

```
REAL(DbKi)                   :: bigben(2),bigben2(2),dtime,etime
```

to

```
REAL                  :: bigben(2),bigben2(2)
```

(or `real(4)`) if you use the GNU intrinsic extension.

If you actually want to call some your own external `dtime`, you must declare an interface block for it.

The same holds for `etime` from https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/ETIME.html